# Clojure (Hiccup): How can I know which submit button got pressed in a form?

Tags: forms, clojure, hiccup

I have a form, using hiccup framework. It looks like this:

```
(form-to {:enctype "multipart/form-data"}
  [:post "/add-data"]

  ...

  (submit-button {:class "btn"} "Save")
  (submit-button {:class "btn} "Clone"))
```

How do I know which submit button got pressed, *without* using jQuery/javascript?

I looked at the Hiccup's documentation for `request`. But, the `request` element does not have a lot of documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A complete example looks like:

```
(ns myapp.routes.home
  (:use [hiccup core form])
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]))

(defn quick-form [& [name message error]]   
  (html
   (form-to {:enctype "multipart/form-data"}
    [:post "/form-out"]
   (text-field "Hello")
   (submit-button {:class "btn" :name "submit"} "Save")
   (submit-button {:class "btn" :name "submit"} "Clone"))))
```

Note that using the same name for both submit buttons allows you to do a simple lookup of the "submit" key in the result map.

```
(defroutes home-routes
 (GET "/form-in" [] (quick-form))
 (POST "/form-out" [:as request] (str (request :multipart-params))))
```

When opening the following page:

```
 http://localhost:3000/form-in
```

And filling the form, the result out of the POST route is:

```
 {"submit" "Save", "Hello" "hello2"}
```

By the way, I found an old useful post about the way the [request map is structured](http://blog.darevay.com/2010/11/a-brief-note-on-compojure-routes-and-requests/) in Compojure, so it makes it easier to destructure it in the Clojure code.

Answer (score 2):

`submit-button` generate HTML `<input type="text" ...>` element. You can add "name" and "value" attributes to them:

```
(submit-button {:name "button" :value "save" :class "btn"} "Save")
(submit-button {:name "button" :value "clone" :class "btn"} "Clone")
```

and find it out in your server side code. In your case lib-noir is used. But recent version of lib-noir no longer provide utils for destructuring requests and encourage people to utilize other libraries like Compojure or bare Ring.

Basically you need:
 - ensure your server side app use `wrap-params` Ring middleware
 - in case the above "Save" button is click, your server side handler for `[:post "/add-data"]` should receive a hash map like this:

```
{:http-method :post
 :uri "/add-data"
 :form-params {"button" "save"
               ;; other form data as key/value pairs
               ;; where: key is input element's "name" attribute and value is input element's "value" attribute
               ...
               }
 ...}
```

I hope you can figure out yourself how to find the value you need in such a map.

More in-depth reading:

https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/wiki/Parameters

Comment: But, how would I find out which button was clicked from server side? I am using lib-noir, but can't figure out how to use its request to get the information.

Comment: server side code varies for libraries/frameworks so it's better mention lib-noir in your question